# How to Flip 2D character in Unity using Euler Angles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2010, euler-angles

i wanna make my character to flip in another direction and moving forward in the direction, but what I got is, My character can only walk in one direction, even if the character turns around, can you help solve it

here's my code

```
public class BirdMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody2D jump;
public bool reverse;

void Start()
{
    jump = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
int jumpstrength = 50;
transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 5f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 && !reverse)
    {
        flip();
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 && reverse)
    {
        flip();
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        jump.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpstrength));
    }

void flip()
{
    reverse = !reverse;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,180,0);
    return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform.Translate takes into account the direction your bird is facing. You make the 2 movements work against each other.

```
transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 5f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
```

If the axis value goes below negative, you tell the bird to walk backwards on x, but this is the bird's local x, not the world's global x. At the same time, you tell it to flip, so it does, and its backwards becomes what used to be its forward.

You can remedy this by using absolute value of the axis.

```
transform.Translate(Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) * 5f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
```

Or asking Translate to use global coords,

```
transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 5f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f, Space.World);
```

That being said, I now wonder how your flip function even works, when all you do is assign 180 on y every time. This won't be able to flip your character more than once. Use transform.Rotate instead.

```
void flip()
{
    reverse = !reverse;
    transform.Rotate(0,180,0);
    return;
}
```

Also the way the brackets are in your example, flip is a nested function of update. Is that intended?

Comment: Mann thats works, thanks Sir for you're help, i can continue my works again, i deeply thanks, Arigato :)